# What's the difference between how heap memory is reclaimed in C++ vs. Java or C#

Tags: java, c#, c++, memory, heap-memory

I know C++ has the destructor and Java/C# has the garbage collectors, but what is the difference between the memory de-allocation?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to exactly what you mean. Are you talking about how a specific implementation does it? The language itself? Idioms of doing it?

Answer (score 7):

C++ has deterministic de-allocations, Java and C# don't.

Most everything else is implementation defined.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ the heap memory **deallocation is manual** unlike the automatic garbage collection in C#/Java which happens periodically.

Using smart pointers, you can simulate the effect of garbage collection in C++ also, but under the hood someone has to write the code which invokes `delete()`/`free()` functions.

C++ also offers the object creation on stack memory which is not dynamically allocated, but it doesn't require any memory management either.

Answer (score 0):

`PL` like `C#/Java` supports `garbage collection` technique, also known by `automatic memory management` technique which deallocates the memory automatically when control flow goes out of scope. The programmer doesn't need to focus on freeing the memory if the `PL` supports `garbage collection` technique.

But `PL` like `C/C++` supports `manual memory management` where programmer controls the memory.`C++` provides the way of allocating and deallocating the memory using new and delete operator

Comment: If `PL` actually means "programming language", you might want to spell that out, or at least don't format it as `code`. It is very confusing.

Comment: Sorry for making it confusing.....I thought the the abbreviation should be given focused so I rather used it......

Comment: Well, it is certainly your choice to make and a matter of personal taste (which is not arguable ;-), but for highlighting text fragments you should rather use _italic_ or **bold**.